# Vue Conditional Classes from Prop Variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So, currently, I have a set of radio buttons on my home.vue page and binding to a child component like so -

```
<div class="radio-toolbar prev-selector">

  <input type="radio" id="one" value="Default" v-model="preview" />
  <label for="one">Default</label>

  <input type="radio" id="two" value="Padded" v-model="preview" />
  <label for="two">Padded</label>

  <input type="radio" id="three" value="Full" v-model="preview" />
  <label for="three">Full</label>

  <span>Picked: {{ preview }}</span>

</div>

<div class="media-wrapper">
  <CardStyle 
    v-bind:card="this.preview"
  />
</div>
```

Which is then passing that "preview" data to the CardStyle Prop.
The prop is receiving it as ['card'] and I can use the data within my component.

However, am wondering how I can use the potential value of "this.preview" (which could be 'default', 'padded' or 'full') as a dynamic class to my child component without having to convert them to a true/false outcome and use -

```
:class="{ default: isDefault, padded: isPadded, full: isFull }"
```

(I have classes called .default, .padded and .full ready to use if it is as simple as passing the data in somehow.)

Comment: Don't know if your component has multiple root elements, but check [this parte of the doc](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#with-components) might clear your line of thought.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `this.preview` has a value of the class name you want to use, just use `:class="this.preview"`.

Answer (score 0):

I built a couple of sample components that demonstrate how to solve your problem.

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <h5>Select Card Style</h5>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="one" value="default" v-model="preview" />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="one">Default</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="two" value="padded" v-model="preview" />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="two">Padded</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="three" value="full" v-model="preview" />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="three">Full</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <card-style :preview="preview" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import CardStyle from './CardStyle.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      CardStyle
    },
    data() {
      return {
        preview: 'default'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

CardStyle.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="card-style">
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <span :class="preview">{{ preview }} Card Style</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      preview: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    },
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .default {
    background-color: burlywood;
  }

  .padded {
    background-color:lightskyblue
  }

  .full {
    background-color:lightcoral
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a computed variable for your field class in your component. This will allow you to select or define what classes to use based on your conditions or case.

```
    computed: {
      myclasses() {
        return [
            'class1',
            'class2',
            [this.condition ? 'class3' : 'class4'],
            { class5: this.othercondition },
        ];
      },
   },
```

Then, just use it your template:

```
<div :class="myclasses"></div>
```